# How to use vcpkg with clang on linux?

Tags: clang, vcpkg, libc++

vcpkg uses the GCC installation package by default on Linux. I see that the official document mentions the custom triplet method, but does not mention the clang tool chain.

How can I specify clang and libc++as the default tool chain of vcpkg?

Answer (score 5):

In order to force vcpkg to compile libraries with a specific toolchain, you can set the variable `VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` to an appropriate toolchain file inside a custom triplet file (aka overlay triplet).

For example, I manually installed clang-13 on my linux environment. The default CXX compiler is GCC.

This is the content of the `clang-13-toolchain.cmake` file I wrote:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang-13")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++-13")

message("clang-13 toolchain CMAKE_C_COMPILER = ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
message("clang-13 toolchain CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER = ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
```

And this is the content of the `x64-linux-clang-13.cmake` triplet file:

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x64)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE dynamic)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)
set(VCPKG_CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../toolchains/clang-13-toolchain.cmake)

message("clang-13 triplet CMAKE_C_COMPILER = ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
message("clang-13 triplet CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER = ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
```

Assuming you have a cmake project and you use vcpkg in 'manifest mode', you must tell vcpkg to use your custom triplet (that uses the clang-13 toolchain), and tell cmake to also use the same toolchain.

So before you call project() in you main CMakeLists.txt, you must set the following:

- `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` - points to the vcpkg toolchain file
- `VCPKG_OVERLAY_TRIPLETS` - points to a directory containing custom triplets (x64-linux-clang-13.cmake)
- `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET` - should be set to "x64-linux-clang-13"
- `VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` - should point to the location of clang-13-toolchain.cmake.

It is convenient to use `CMakePresets.json` file for this.